# In react can I render a component's children without a wrapper?

Tags: reactjs

I want to do:

```
  render: () ->
      {@props.children}
```

It is making me do:

```
  render: () ->
      <div>{@props.children}</div>
```

The reason I want to do the former is because the rendered children have their owner-based context set. But if I render them with the  wrapper then the  element which is the parent does not have its context set. This then generates a warning:

owner-based and parent-based contexts differ (values: `undefined` vs `[object Object]`) for key (x)

This is discussed here: https://gist.github.com/jimfb/0eb6e61f300a8c1b2ce7

But no solution is offered.

The warning occurs because the component which renders the child is the 'owner' and that is settting context but the div wrapper element is the 'parent' and has no context. My idea was to get rid of the div. But I can't get rid of it.

Comment: Hm, the `div` should not affect the context. Do you have more code or, even better, a JSBin example (specifically the component that renders this one, and where the context is set/used)?

Comment: I also want to do this, for CSS reasons.

Comment: This was an unrelated problem. In fact I am able to render the children without an enclosing div element. (The conflict was between an instance of fluxxor added by the FluxMixin and an instance added by a component create factor wrapper used with react-router). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I've used the following code to only use a wrapper `<span>` on `text` children:

```
render() {
  if (!this.props.children) {
    return null;
  } else if (React.isValidElement(this.props.children)) {
    return this.props.children;
  }
  return <span>{this.props.children}</span>;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With React 16=>

```
render() {
    return <React.Fragment>{this.props.children}</React.Fragment>;
}
```

or

```
render() {
    return <>{this.props.children}</>;
}
```

Comment: it works but leads to an annoying warning: Fragments should contain more than one child

Answer (score 1):

In situations where a single child is required:

```
render() {
    return React.Children.only(this.props.children)
}
```

This is what react-redux uses in `connect()`, FWIW.